# How to add a foreign key to already existing models in rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rake-task

For simplification, please assume my schema is as [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp) (or see next sentence - my actual tables are very similar, in that I have two tables which I am trying to join by the primary key in one on the foreign key of the other)

So for the example, we have: a Persons table with PersonID as a primary key, and an Orders table, with PersonID as a foreign key.

Supposing the tables already exist in my app with no associations set, I believe I'd do the following:

1. Place `has_many :orders` in the Persons model, and `belongs_to :person` in the Order model
2. Generate a new migration, e.g. rails g migration migrationName

I am not sure what to do next. I think it's to put this in the migration file (and run rake db:migrate)?

```
add_foreign_key :orders, :person
```

In my actual tables, the foreign key column has a funny name (nothing to do with the table it's joining to) - I think what I need to do may change but again I am not sure?

One last note, I know someone will suggest I read [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#foreign-keys). The thing is I have spent hours reading it and other sources and I have several other complicating factors in the association I am trying to define (association is optional on both tables), and I also do not know how to quickly tell if it has actually worked (at the moment I try to use some Arel code in the rails console to see if a join returns any results - I do not know of any easier way that exists)

Comment: Adding `has_many` and `belongs_to` does not require to migrate if you already have the fields in the database. If association is optional, don't add foreign keys.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this question through a random Google search because I was looking for something similar. Create your migration and make sure it looks something like this:

```
class AddPersonToOrders < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    # No need for this line because you said:
    # "an Orders table, with PersonID as a foreign key"
    # add_reference   :orders, :person

    # This is what I think you are missing:
    add_foreign_key :orders, :persons, column: :person_id
    # If this doesn’t work, try to change the `person_id`
    # column name to that funny column name you say you have.
  end
end
```

Comment: I tried with the funny column name and I get "ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey: PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR:  insert or update on table "orders" violates foreign key constraint". For good measure I swapped :orders and :persons and I get a similar error

Comment: How’s your `schema.rb` like?

Comment: @user5783745 Could be that the data is inconsistent. Make sure all rows have a valid value in that column. Most importantly, make sure that the column references existing rows in the foreign table.